# Ionic prevent navigation on leave

Tags: ionic-framework

I there a way to prevent navigation before leaving a view? I've found the $ionicView.beforeLeave event, which is called before leaving a view, but I dont know how to stop the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user... I've solved it with this code:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if(isViewDirty() && !$scope.ignoreDirty){
        event.preventDefault();
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Leave Page',
            template: 'Are you sure?'
        });
        confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
            if(res) {
                $scope.ignoreDirty = true; //Prevent loop
                $state.go(toState, toParams);
            }
        });
    }
});
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
    $scope.ignoreDirty = false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic framework uses angular UI Router, UI Router fire events before and after changing states. May be the **stateChangeStart** would help you.

For details and implementation, refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) please